# PHP Fatal error with nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, fastcgi, php

I'm having, in a PHP form, when I'm submiting one email as a suscriber in a Wordpress theme, the next error in error.log:

2013/08/03 21:39:22 [error] 19544#0: *11 `FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: require_once(TEMPLATEPATH/functions/theme-functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /web/domain.com/public/wp-content/themes/launcheffect/functions.php on line 151`

PHP message: `PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'TEMPLATEPATH/functions/theme-functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /web/domain.com/public/wp-content/themes/launcheffect/functions.php on line 151" while reading response header from upstream, client: 71.28.74.212, server: www.domain.com, request: "POST /wp-content/themes/launcheffect/post.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com", referrer: "http://www.domain.com/"`

I've been reading about permissions, about nginx and fastcgi, about PHPfpm, reviewing my config...without success. More, I've other sites working perfectly, and that theme worked well some days ago.

Of course I've that file/directory.

My nginx.conf:

http://pastebin.com/5VB1BzHj

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like `TEMPLATEPATH` is getting outputted as it is. It should be concatenated: `TEMPLATEPATH . functions/theme-functions.php`

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a little more? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ok, I got it with strace, but nothing special that I can see :(

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example error it appears you are not formatting the require correctly. It should look something like this:

```
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions/theme-functions.php');
```

Make certain that you are also defining your TEMPLATEPATH.

```
define("TEMPLATEPATH ", "/this/is/your/path");
```

In the end, this should output a string:

```
/this/is/your/path/functions/theme-functions.php
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem, double check your file paths and file names as mine was caused by a case sensitive file path where I had missed an Uppercase letter